# Why does background running service cannot get and/or update the locations?

Tags: android, service, locationmanager, forceclose

I am a newbie to Android. I am running a service in the background to get the changing latitudes and longitudes. I have asked this question earlier but couldn't get the appropriate answer to it. I have a service in the background which is supposed to keep track of the changing positions. I realised that the coordinates are not getting changed or they are set to null. I have tried different suggestions but the same problem persists. Please can somebody explain me step by step what to do. I have been sitting this for the past one week. My error logs and codes are as follows:

Error logs

```
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483): java.lang.NullPointerException
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at com.example.broadcast.Ser.onLocationChanged(Ser.java:131)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:263)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:196)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:212)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
 03-22 06:26:29.622: E/AndroidRuntime(12483):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And the code of my Service :

```
 public class Ser extends Service implements LocationListener {

 public Location getLocation(String provider) {
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE, MIN_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
        if (locationManager != null) {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            String l1=String.valueOf(latitude);
            String l2=String.valueOf(longitude);

        }

        }


    return location;
}

  @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(isNetworkEnabled==true && isGPSEnabled==false)
    {
        getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
    else if(isGPSEnabled==true && isNetworkEnabled==false)
    {
        getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    else if(isGPSEnabled==true && isNetworkEnabled==false)
    {
        getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    else if(isGPSEnabled==true && isNetworkEnabled==true )
    {
        getLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
    else
    {
        cellid();
    }



    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    //this.location=location;
    if(location!=null)
    {
    double latitude =location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    String l1=String.valueOf(latitude);
    String l2=String.valueOf(longitude);
    val=db.taskid(l1, l2);
    String silent="Silent",vibrate="Vibrate";

    if(val.get("heading").compareTo(silent)==0)

{
        AudioManager audioManager= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT); 
    }

    else if(val.get("heading").compareTo(vibrate)==0)
    {
        AudioManager audioManager= (AudioManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE); 
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar app, which uses a service to retrieve locations. In the oncreate method initialise google services and the location location manager like so:

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
private Location location;
private int TIME_IN_MILLI = 20000;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Getting Google Play availability status
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    // Google Play Services are unavailable
    if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available
        int requestCode = 10;
        Log.i("Info", "Google Play Services are unavailable");
    }else { 
        //Get GPS Location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TIME_IN_MILLI, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Once initialised, then your onLocationChanged callback will be hit when you location is acquired and updated ever 20 seconds as set in the TIME_IN_MILLI variable.